# В Outlook не отображаются картинки из почтовой рассылки

Tags: html, вёрстка-email

Сверстал шаблон почтовой рассылки, проверил в основных почтовых клиентах.

Везде всё нормально, но в Outlook не отображаются картинки.

Пробовал сверстать и так:

```
<img src="https://site.tld/newsletters/spacer.gif" alt="spacer" width="1px" height="1px">
```

и через data-uri:

```
<img src=" data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAPXz8wAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="spacer" width="1px" height="1px">
```

Но не работает ни так, ни так.

Когда приходит письмо нажимаю на письме "показать рисунки", но ничего не видно. Отправитель находится в доверенных, так же и весь домен (собственно, отправлял себе на ak@site.tld)

В чём проблема? Надо как-то верстать по-хитрому или что-то в настройках поменять?

Answer (score 1):

Проблема не связана с самой вёрсткой, проблема связана с настройками.

Во-первых, в Outlook нужно Файл - Параметры - Центр управления безопасностью - Параметры центра управления безопасностью убрать галку на пункте "Не загружать автоматически рисунки в письмах HTML и элементах RSS"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Во-вторых, нужно в свойствах Internet Explorer убрать галку "Не сохранять шифрованные страницы на диск" (в случае если картинки загружаются с веб-сайта по протоколу https)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]